# R - Type in legend

Tags: r, plot

I am making a plot and have type `o` and `b`. What is the similar to if I want to make it the legend?

I have tried this but it doesn't look alike:

```
col=c('red','black'),pch=c(10,21),pt.bg ='white'
```

Illustrated:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? Hint: `?legend`

Comment: I have only tried the one explained above. that is the closest I came.

Comment: if you really want a legend showing both o and b, you might have to do that yourself. if you just want a legend with both lines and points, simply give both pch and lwd to legend. I used both too many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible hack is to make the legend appear like `type = b` is to use a line type with large gaps.

```
plot(1)
legend("topleft", legend = "fish", pch = 20, lty = "6a")
```

looks OK. Obviously with smaller symbols, thicker lines or whatever, this might look awful and need tweaking.